# Is it possible to "sandbox" arbitrary JavaScript to only operate on one <div> and not the whole document?

Tags: javascript, security

what I am trying to do is to force some arbitrary JavaScript code to execute "inside" a DOM element, e.g. `<div>`. In other words, is it possible to make a piece of code "thinking" that `<div>` is the root of document hierarchy (or `<body>` of a document)?

**Real life example:**

Let's say we have a page that allows executing JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Executor</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <input/>
  <button onclick="$('div').html(eval($('input').val()))">
    Execute
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

The code has access to entire document and can modify it, e.g:

```
$("input").hide()
```

Will prevent me from writing any stupid code any more ;-)

Is is possible to restrict the area of effect for some piece of JavaScript code? and how to do it if it is possible?

Best regards.

**Edit:**

The code I want to execute might be everything. If Your solution is based on some kind of modification of the given code, please describe how to do it the right way.

**Edit2:**

First of all, I do not know why I get a down-vote.

Secondly, the code I will execute is someone else's arbitrary code, not mine.

**To make everything clear:**

What I am really trying to do is to simulate a browser somehow. Get the content of some web page, and insert in into mine. This is relatively easy when we decided to turn off JavaScript and cut out all places where it might appear, but this is something I cannot do. For now I want to limit only the DOM modification (the malicious code). I will work on redirects and cookies later, when I have a base idea.

Comment: Some more context of what you're trying to do might be helpful. When you talk about malicious JavaScript, often things like changing cookies, hidden iframes, or redirecting the page are part of the discussion. Trying to limit those to a particular div doesn't really have any meaning--a redirect doesn't have a context on the page like a hide() does.

Comment: What you're describing is often called a "wrapper attack" where party B puts a wrapper around party A's web content and claims it as their (B's) own.  There are many web sites that actively fight against being wrapped because it leads to user confusion about site identity and could be used for phishing attacks. There is a Javascript technique to force a page into a top window if it has been loaded into an iframe. Are you trying to defeat this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to achieve complete isolation and encapsulation of a chunk of code is to put it into an iframe, and put it on a subdomain of your site so that the domain name of the outer HTML page is not identical to the inner HTML page.  Inside the iframe, the JavaScript will see only the DOM of the iframe URL and will have no access to the outer DOM. This isolation is enforced by the browser security model.

The plus side to this technique is that you can have high confidence that the script running inside the iframe will not leak out and steal data from your outer page.  This isolation is also the downside - it's harder to share data between the outer page and inner page. To provide controlled access or sharing of data between the iframe and the outer page, there are a variety of cross-domain data sharing techniques you could investigate.  If you only need to throw arguments "at" the iframe inner page, you could pass the data on the URL as query params.  If you need two-way data exchange, you could use domain-lowering techniques to bring the domain names in line briefly so that the browser will allow data exchange between the outer and inner pages.

Since you are proposing to eval() arbitrary code entered in an input control, you definitely should shield your main page logic from potential hackery.  Use an iframe.

Comment: Executing code not necessarily mean `eval` for me. The code will come from other page, (eg. loaded by AJAX). If You ware forbidden to use iframe, what would You use instead?

Comment: If I were forbidden to use iframe to protect my web assets from arbitrary external code, I'd send a letter through postal mail instead. ;>

The browser/HTML/DOM does provide a way to isolate untrusted JavaScript code from the rest of your site.  It's called iframe.

I don't know of any other way of achieving this isolation other than writing your own browser or native executable browser plugin.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer is that the best way to do two-way communication is not "domain-lowering techniques" but using window.postMessage().

Comment: @hallvors Yes, window.postMessage() is a much better cross-domain technique today. It wasn't available in most browsers 3 years ago when this answer was written.

Answer (score 6):

One approach could be encapsulating all of the code that is need to be secured, with an anonymous function, and pass all environmental parameters with similar objects but modified not to allow global DOM manipulations, for simplest example

```
(function(document,JQuery,$,window){ //make sure all global access methods are here

//eval code here or just copy and paste

})(modifiedDocument,modifiedJQuery,modifiedJQuery,modifiedWindow);
```

Now the question may come into one's mind, how we can modify the document object? One aproach maybe

```
var modifiedDocument = function(){

    this.getElementById = function(id){ //one of global accessing functions

         //check if given id is withing the restriction div
         return document.getElementById(id);

         //if found element is not withing restriction div just return null or what is default
         return null;
    }

}
```

Self-invoking anonymous functions allow us to prevent global variable collisions, and it is used in many well known libraries like jQuery.

To be able to apply this method, first you have to determine every possible way, how a script tries to read or write a global DOM object. I cannot give you complete solution because using this method it is apparently a project may consume my entire week, but this may light your way!

Answer (score 0):

This is from [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) documentation.  Is that helpful?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="man-news" />

      <input name="milkman" />
      <input name="letterman2" />
      <input name="newmilk" />
    <script>$("input[name*='man']").val("has man in it!");</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This unfortunately is not helpful. The problem is the code I will be executing won't be my code actually. Someone might write some pure JavaScript malicious code. I need to be able to restrict any inputed executable string to some DOM area.

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery is based on the `document` element, but you can pass a second parameter that tells jQuery where to "start", which essentially limits the execution to that element...

```
var divToRestrictTo = $("#myDiv");
$("input", divToRestrictTo); // will only look within the DIV
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how You possibly know the inputed code will use jQuery? and use it just how You describe it? I will say this again: I won't know the inputed code, this might be arbitrary, someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible (and might even be practically possible) to control the JS execution environment to such an extent that you can sandbox a script. However, it's very, very involved to do so. It's a lot of hard work, and using an IFRAME is recommended for just about any case of this requirement.

If IFRAMEs really are out of the question for some reason, you could try looking at the Caja project:

http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

I have not used Caja myself, but it sounds like it might do what you need. You will probably have to pay some severe complexity cost though. The IFRAME is basically the web architecture's answer to your use case, and most other solutions will resemble elaborate and complex hacks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a long time ago, but I stumbled on it recently because I have a similar situation, where I need to embed 3rd party content, including javascript.

I came across a google project called caja (https://developers.google.com/caja/) which in their own words:

> is a tool for making third party HTML, CSS and JavaScript safe to embed in your website. It enables rich interaction between the embedding page and the embedded applications. Caja uses an object-capability security model to allow for a wide range of flexible security policies, so that your website can effectively control what embedded third party code can do with user data.

I have not used it yet, but plan on trying it out soon.

Comment: does caja requires a separate webserver to execute javascript in a separate thread ???????/